# iOS framework works okay without "linking" to app, why is it needed then?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I'm experimenting with HealthKit in my app and I've noticed that I can `import HealthKit`, use it's features, compile and run the app without the `HealthKit.framework` being linked to my app in "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" (in General target settings). If that is the case, why is it required to link to system frameworks in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

Lion's answer is correct, but incomplete.

Xcode introduced something called **Modules**. Modules were introduced in Xcode 5.0 and is an alternate way of including/importing files.

Other than some compilation optimizations it includes something that's called **Auto Linking**.

> When a source file includes a header from a framework that supports
>   modules, the compiler generates extra information in the object file
>   to automatically link in that framework

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_5_0.html)

Swift uses modules by default. Objective-C uses modules when you use `@import` instead of `#import`.

So in short, Xcode always uses auto-linking unless you're using `#import`.

[You can read here for more details.](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/modules-and-precompiled-headers/)

Answer (score 0):

No there is no need with latest `sdk` or say latest xcode. If you can import framework and can use it without adding it in `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` then there is no need to add that framework to `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`, because by default it is already linked with your project.